# Hi . I a new to unix scripting, can someone one help me on the below

Tags: bash, unix

I have two files.

file 1-- this is sql generate file with | delimiter

```
sabari|27|22-12-1990|CHENNAI|
Siva|29|13-11-1989|CHENNAI|
```

File 2 - I have created hard core file

```
Sabari|-|-|-|-|

Siva|-|-|-|-|

Ravi|-|-|-|-|

Bali|-|-|-|-|
```

I want to compare and place the value in File-1 from File-2 if the value not in f1.

Desired Out put

```
sabari|27|22-12-1990|CHENNAI|

Siva|29|13-11-1989|CHENNAI|

Ravi|-|-|-|-|

Bali|-|-|-|-|
```

Can some one help me /

Comment: Please select a more appropriate headline for the question.

Answer (score 0):

I would do:

```
awk '{k=tolower($1)}NR==FNR{a[k]=$0;next} k in a{$0=a[k]}1' FS=\| file1 file2
```

Make a pass over the first file, storing everything in memory hashed on the first entry.  Then pass over the second file, checking if the line was given in the first file and print the line from that file if it was seen.  The "tolower" just makes comparisons case insensitive.

Maybe it's clearer written as:

```
awk '{k=tolower($1)}NR==FNR{a[k]=$0;next}{print k in a ? a[k] : $0}' FS=\| file1 file2
```

The NR==FNR technique is a common way to pre-load data from the first input file.

Comment: [sabarinathan] awk '{k=tolower($1)}NR==FNR{a[k]=$0;next}{print k in a ? a[k] : $0}' FS=\| MF_STATUS.txt JOBNULL.txt
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: illegal statement near line 1